# What would be the different features of Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: release-management, 15.04

What would be the different features of Ubuntu 15.04 compared to so far releases?

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://imacify.com/2014/12/fever-for-ubuntu-15-04-started-soon-after-the-release-of-14-10/) ? Anything specific you want to know?

Comment: 15.04 is not finalised yet, although it is getting very near release so almost all features in the current pre-releases will be the same as in the final release.

Answer (score 1):

The [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes) point to the [blueprints](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+specs) that have a good summary of work done for 15.04.

Comment: and it's released! [email](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2015-April/000195.html) and final [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes)